# Libgdx render for a rectangle array different textures

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am developing a game with libgdx and i got stuck at a point. So My SpriteBatch draws for all the Rectangles that are in an array with the same texture but I want that every single one has its own texture. MY Code looks like this

```
    public class GameScreen implements Screen{

    final MrJetpack game;

    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    ShapeRenderer rend;
    private Array<Rectangle> raindrops;

    Texture enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4,endScreen;
    TextureRegion[] enemys = new TextureRegion[4];

    private int random;


    public GameScreen(final MrJetpack game){

this.game = game;

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

enemy1  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("boxk.png"));
enemy2  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("boxg.png"));
enemy3  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("kugel.png"));
enemy4  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("kugelk.png"));

enemys[0] = new TextureRegion(enemy1);      
enemys[1] = new TextureRegion(enemy2);    
enemys[2] = new TextureRegion(enemy3);     
enemys[3] = new TextureRegion(enemy4); 

raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();

rend = new ShapeRenderer();
batch = new SpriteBatch();

   }


   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, (float)148/255,(float) 255/255, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  camera.update();




  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  rend.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
  rend.rect(0, 0, 800, 10);
  rend.rect(0, 160, 800, 10);
  rend.rect(0, 320, 800, 10);
  rend.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
  rend.end();

  batch.begin();
  for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops) {
      batch.draw(enemys[random], raindrop.x - 10, raindrop.y);
   }
  batch.end();


  if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > spawnTime){
      spawnRaindrop();  
      }
  Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
     Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
     raindrop.x -= 20 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

     if(raindrop.x < 0) {
         spawnRaindrop();
         iter.remove();
     }
     }


    }


  private void spawnRaindrop() {
  Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
  raindrop.x = 800;
  stages = MathUtils.random(1, 3);
  random = MathUtils.random(0, 3);
  raindrop.width = 30;
  raindrop.height = 53;
  raindrops.add(raindrop);
  lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
     }
```

So what actually happening is that everytime a new Rectangle spawns in the screen the other ones who were already displayed change the Texture so every Rectangle got the same Texture . Any solutions or examples?

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Daad4.jpg 
This is my problem for people who understood my question false :)
Like you can see the texture is changing for all the other rectangles but i want everyone to have their static texture

Comment: You need to use the Sprite class instead of Rectangle, or some other class that you create yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They told you, one way to do it, but I see you do not clear, I'll put more or less as you might do.

I'll try to make the form more similar to what you already have in your code.

**note**
this code may have syntax error, among others, becouse I'm doing from the editor StackOverflow.

1- create a class that is derived from sprite, for example something like:

```
public class SpriteRaindrop extends Sprite{

     Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();

public SpriteRaindrop(Texture t, int srcWidth, 
                                 int srcHeigth, 
                                 float posX, 
                                 float posY){

      super(t, srcWidth, srcHeigth);

      raindrop.x      = posX;
      raindrop.y      = posY;
      raindrop.width  = srcWidth;
      raindrop.height = srcHeigth;

      setPosition(posX, posY);
 }

 public void updateR(){
     raindrod.x = getX();
     raindrod.y = getY();
 }
}
```

This your code with with any changes

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen{

    final MrJetpack game;

    OrthographicCamera camera;
    SpriteBatch batch;
    ShapeRenderer rend;
    private Array<SpriteRaindrop> raindrops;

    Texture enemy1,enemy2,enemy3,enemy4,endScreen;
    TextureRegion[] enemys = new TextureRegion[4];

    private int random;


    public GameScreen(final MrJetpack game){

this.game = game;

camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);

enemy1  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("boxk.png"));
enemy2  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("boxg.png"));
enemy3  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("kugel.png"));
enemy4  = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("kugelk.png"));

enemys[0] = new TextureRegion(enemy1);      
enemys[1] = new TextureRegion(enemy2);    
enemys[2] = new TextureRegion(enemy3);     
enemys[3] = new TextureRegion(enemy4); 

raindrops = new Array<SpriteRaindrop>();

rend = new ShapeRenderer();
batch = new SpriteBatch();

   }


   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, (float)148/255,(float) 255/255, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  camera.update();




  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  rend.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
  rend.rect(0, 0, 800, 10);
  rend.rect(0, 160, 800, 10);
  rend.rect(0, 320, 800, 10);
  rend.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
  rend.end();

  batch.begin();

  for(SpriteRaindrop raindrop: raindrops) {
      //raindrop.translatex(-10f);
      //what is raindrop.y value
      raindrop.updateR();
      raindrop.draw(batch);
   }

  batch.end();


  if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > spawnTime){
      spawnRaindrop();  
  }

  Iterator<SpriteRaindrop> iter = raindrops.iterator();

  while(iter.hasNext()) {

     SpriteRaindrop raindrop = iter.next();

     raindrop.translateX(-20f * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

         if(raindrop.getX() < 0) {
             spawnRaindrop();
             iter.remove();
         }
 }


 }


  private void spawnRaindrop() {

      stages = MathUtils.random(1, 3);
      random = MathUtils.random(0, 3);

      lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

      SpriteRaindrop raindrop = new SpriteRaindrop(enemys[random],
                                                   30, 53, 
                                                   800, 0);
      raindrops.add(raindrop);
     }
```

this is just an idea, but I think it can work, I hope you help

Comment: @user3629585 If this answer helps or solves your problem, cosidera upvote / accept because I have several responses like yours that remain valid are not upvote, and perhaps at some point I can not answer more by the low rate of acceptances, and look this http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Change the constructor of SpriteRaindrop to public SpriteRaindrop(TextureRegion t, int srcWidth, 
                                int srcHeigth, 
                                float posX, 
                                float posY){

     super(t);

     raindrop.x      = posX;
     raindrop.y      = posY;
     raindrop.width  = srcWidth;
     raindrop.height = srcHeigth;

     setPosition(posX, posY);
} and then it works . Thanks bro for helping me out

Comment: @Angel Angel
Please,hel me
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342642/sprites-array-merges-the-when-rendering-sprites/38344125#38344125

Answer (score 0):

The variable random is global for class, once a new sprite spawns it sets the value to new random value and all of them are draw by:

batch.draw(enemys[random], raindrop.x - 10, raindrop.y);

You need to track this together with location per instance.