# Sprites array merges the when rendering sprites

Tags: java, libgdx

Sprite bucketImage, background, r1, r2, r5,
            r10, r20, r50, r100, r200, r500, k1, k2, k5, k10, k20, k50;

I create objects in the method called spawnRaindrop(). I have an array of sprites and I want to sprites were changed in the cycle as it is now, it works, but the images are merged with each other.

```
  sprites = new Sprite[15];
    r1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r1"));
    r1.flip(false, true);
    r2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r2"));
    r2.flip(false, true);
    r5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r5"));
    r5.flip(false, true);
    r10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r10"));
    r10.flip(false, true);
    r20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r20"));
    r20.flip(false, true);
    r50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r50"));
    r50.flip(false, true);
    r100 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r100"));
    r100.flip(false, true);
    r200 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r200"));
    r200.flip(false, true);
    r500 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("r500"));
    r500.flip(false, true);
    k1 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k1"));
    k1.flip(false, true);
    k2 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k2"));
    k2.flip(false, true);
    k5 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k5"));
    k5.flip(false, true);
    k10 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k10"));
    k10.flip(false, true);
    k20 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k20"));
    k20.flip(false, true);
    k50 = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("k50"));
    k50.flip(false, true);
    sprites[0] = r1;
    sprites[1] = r2;
    sprites[2] = r5;
    sprites[3] = r10;
    sprites[4] = r20;
    sprites[5] = r50;
    sprites[6] = r100;
    sprites[7] = r200;
    sprites[8] = r500;
    sprites[9] = k1;
    sprites[10] = k2;
    sprites[11] = k5;
    sprites[12] = k10;
    sprites[13] = k20;
    sprites[14] = k50;
```

Create game object

```
   private void spawnRaindrop() {
    Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
    raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800 - 100);
    raindrop.y = 480;
    raindrop.width = 100;
    raindrop.height = 100;
    raindrops.add(raindrop);
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
```

Create and draw array sprite

```
 game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);

    for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++) {

            game.batch.draw(sprites[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
        }
    }
    game.batch.end();
```

RESULT:
I attached the picture, and it can be seen that the images accumulate on each other

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @ Edvin Tenovim
how to draw an array of sprits through  game.batch.draw(sprites, raindrop.x, raindrop.y); correctly???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that you are using the same `raindrop.x` and `raindrop.y` coordinates for all sprites!

```
for (Rectangle raindrop : raindrops)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sprites.length - 1; i++)
    {
        // The following will draw ALL sprites at the same location!
        game.batch.draw(sprites[i], raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
    }
}
```

What you can try is to create a new class called (for example): `Raindrops` and then in this class maintain a single x,y coordinate for each individual image:

```
class Raindrop
{
    Vector2 coordinates;
    Sprite sprite;
}
```

Then in your `spawnRaindrop` method, create an array of these Raindrop's and an individual (random?) image for each.

EDIT: I wrote the following code directly here without testing anything, so it will most likely have some errors, but nothing you shouldn't be able to fix yourself...

```
// This goes into your initialisation method
String regions[] = {"r1", "r2", "r5", "r10", "etc etc etc"}
Raindrop raindrops[] = new Raindrop[15];
for ( int i = 0; i < raindrops.length; i++ )
{
    raindrop[i] = new Raindrop();
    raindrop[i].coordinate.x = MathUtils.random(screenWidth);
    raindrop[i].coordinate.y = MathUtils.random(screenHeight);
    raindrop[i].sprite = atlas.findRegion(regions[(int)MathUtils.random(regions.length)]);
}
```

Then your main loop should look something like this:

```
game.batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
for ( Raindrop raindrop : raindrops )
{
    game.batch.draw(raindrop.sprite, raindrop.coordinate.x, raindrop.coordinate.y);
}
game.batch.end();
```

Comment: Yes, I want to draw the sprites at random. how to implement it, help?

Comment: my problem similar to this|
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30198058/libgdx-render-for-a-rectangle-array-different-textures

Comment: Raindrop raindrops[] = new Raindrop[15];
I do not have this class
I create an object
Array<Rectangle> raindrops;

look this, my example
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game

To facilitate the creation of raindrops we'll write a method called spawnRaindrop() which instantiates a new Rectangle, sets it to a random position at the top edge of the screen and adds it to the raindrops array.

Comment: @upward, I know you don't have the class `Raindrop`, which is why I suggested you create it. Do you not know how to create a new class? If you don't, then you *really* need to learn that first!